# Reading Array and Setting Parameters to Specific Values

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have a parameter $return.

When I set "print_r($return);" I get the following:

```
{"allresponses":"{\"adm_big_picture\":null,\"adm_group\":null,\"adm_group_message\":null,\"adm_large_icon\":null,\"adm_small_icon\":null,\"adm_sound\":null,\"amazon_background_data\":false,\"android_accent_color\":null,\"android_group\":null,\"android_group_message\":null,\"android_led_color\":null,\"android_sound\":null,\"android_visibility\":null,\"app_id\":\"XXXX\",\"big_picture\":null,\"buttons\":null,\"canceled\":false,\"chrome_big_picture\":null,\"chrome_icon\":null,\"chrome_web_icon\":\"\",\"chrome_web_image\":\"\",\"content_available\":false,\"contents\":{\"en\":\"This is a new message.\"},\"converted\":0,\"data\":null,\"delayed_option\":\"immediate\",\"delivery_time_of_day\":\"4:00 PM\",\"errored\":0,\"excluded_segments\":[],\"failed\":0,\"firefox_icon\":\"\",\"headings\":{\"en\":\"New Message\"},\"id\":\"12\",\"include_player_ids\":null,\"included_segments\":[\"All\"],\"ios_badgeCount\":null,\"ios_badgeType\":null,\"ios_category\":null,\"ios_sound\":null,\"isAdm\":false,\"isAndroid\":false,\"isChrome\":false,\"isChromeWeb\":true,\"isFirefox\":true,\"isIos\":false,\"isSafari\":true,\"isWP\":false,\"isWP_WNS\":false,\"large_icon\":null,\"priority\":null,\"queued_at\":1492523636,\"remaining\":0,\"send_after\":1492523636,\"small_icon\":null,\"successful\":3,\"tags\":null,\"filters\":null,\"template_id\":null,\"ttl\":null,\"url\":\"\",\"web_buttons\":null,\"wp_sound\":null,\"wp_wns_sound\":null}"}
```

I would like to take specific values and assign them to a parameter, for example to take value of app_id and set it as a value of $appId so when I do echo $appId, the value xxxx is printed on screen.

Have tried using the following, but not returning results:

```
$obj= json_decode($return);
$appId = $obj->allresponses->app_id;
echo $appId;
```

Can someone guide me please?

Thanks :)

Comment: You need to decode `$obj->allresponses` also, then you can access it.

Comment: $obj= json_decode($return);
    
    $obj2 = json_decode($obj->allresponses);
    
    echo $obj2->allresponses->app_id;

Comment: @Rizier123 do you mean like this?

Comment: Almost prefect. Just when you decoded the second json you don't have to access `->allresponses` again, since you already toke the value of that property, which is also a json string, and decoded it. So just do: `echo $obj2->app_id;`

Comment: thanks your method worked as well :)

Comment: If you don't have what you have inside an object/array always just do: `print_r($variable);` and see what you have for yourself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I need to decode the `json` object **twice**, i.e.:

```
$obj = json_decode($return);
$obj = json_decode($obj->allresponses);
$appId = $obj->app_id;
echo $appId;
# XXXX
```

---

[PHP Demo](https://eval.in/784797)

Comment: Thanks, just what was needed :)

Answer (score 0):

You have a json object inside that object. You must decode the secondary object as well. Here is how:

```
$firstObject = json_decode($return);
$secondObject = json_decode($firstObject);
$appId = $secondObject->app_id;
echo $appId;
```

Comment: Third line should output $appId = $secondObject->app_id; ($secondObject instead of secondObject)?